# Android draw ImageView programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to draw an image into my canvas. In the constructor:

```
this.Icon = new ImageView(context);
this.Icon.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon);
this.Icon.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height);
```

And in the `OnDraw`:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    this.Icon.SetX(x);
    this.Icon.SetY(y);
    this.Icon.RequestLayout();
    this.Icon.Draw(canvas);
}
```

It is not appearing. Am I missing something?

My class extends `View`

Comment: Where you define Icon? What class extends your class? If it's simple view, then your code will not work? If it's viewGroup, then have you added `addView` method?

Comment: My class extends View. Icon is a public property in the class.

Comment: So I can't put an ImageView inside of a View? Is there any other way to draw an image inside a View?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to draw an image inside a view:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon);
var scaledBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, false);
canvas.DrawBitmap(scaledBitmap, x, y, paint);
```

But is this good practice? Is it more expensive on resources to draw it this way?

Comment: It's a bad way since you doing a heavy computations in onDraw method, which is needed to be as much lightweight as possible. So you need to decode your bitmap in some other place and keep reference to it. Or you can create a BitmapDrawable which doing 'drawing bitmap' work for you and keep reference to it in your view. And then in 'onDraw' method call bitmapDrawable.draw(canvas)

Comment: Oh, almost forgot. In your case you can provide `Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon )`. then store myIcon reference as a field and in `onDraw` method you can call `myIcon.draw(canvas)`.